# Is there a way to use ConvertFrom-String with a Class?

Tags: powershell

This [PowerShell documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string?view=powershell-5.1#example-4--use-an-expression-as-the-value-of-the-templatecontent-parameter--save-the-results-in-a-variable-) file shows how to use a string based template in conjuction with the `ConvertFrom-String` operation.  Here is the example it shows:

```
$template = @'
{Name*:Phoebe Cat}, {phone:425-123-6789}, {age:6}
{Name*:Lucky Shot}, {phone:(206) 987-4321}, {age:12}
'@

$testText = @'
Phoebe Cat, 425-123-6789, 6
Lucky Shot, (206) 987-4321, 12
Elephant Wise, 425-888-7766, 87
Wild Shrimp, (111)  222-3333, 1
'@

$PersonalData = $testText | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template
Write-output ("Pet items found: " + ($PersonalData.Count))
$PersonalData
```

I prefer using classes to the template strings shown here.  So for this example it would look like this:

```
class Entry {
  [string] Name
  [string] Phone
  [string] Age
}
```

**Is there a way to use a class like that in the `ConvertFrom-String` method?**

NOTE: Part of the reason I want to do this is so I can add another array to the output (that is filled in later).  So in this example, my `Entry` class would also have a property defined as `[System.Collections.ArrayList] Addresses`.

Comment: Afaik, there is no easy way to do this with a `ConvertFrom-String` template or a (indirect) method. Personally, I wouldn't use a `ConvertFrom-String` template for this as it is quiet loosely and therefore can easily go sideways. Instead, I would build a `[string]` based constructor in your class with a regular expression to divide the properties. The syntax should than look like this: `... |ForEach-Object { [Entry]$_ }`

Comment: I looked over the same resource you've probably looked over as well as the powershell github which doesn't have the code for this cmdlet yet (I'm guessing you already checked that too).  From what I can gather, and the fact it's able to parse a single count here string to form an object culture....  I think it's custom code in the cmdlet itself.  I couldn't find any other native method tied to any kind of string in .net that provides the same functionality.  I'd recommend putting in a suggestion on the powershell github to expose this feature.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert-FromSting` as the cmdlet clearly specifies in the documentation works only with structured properties from string content.

PowerShell classes might help you out though:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.1